# Encountering 'Module 'camera_avfoundation' not found' Error in Flutter Project

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, camera

I'm developing an iOS app using Flutter and encountering an error during Xcode build: 'Module 'camera_avfoundation' not found'. I've attempted the following steps without resolving the issue.

Executed flutter clean and flutter pub get.
Performed a Clean Build Folder in Xcode.
Checked and ran pod install in ios/Podfile.
Added NSCameraUsageDescription and NSMicrophoneUsageDescription to Info.plist.
My Flutter version is 3.16.0 and the camera plugin version is 0.10.5+5 Are there any other solutions I should try? Any ideas or advice on what might be causing this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this, I am having a similar challenge. I am wondering if it might be caused by the indentaton in the pod file since I edited it.